# Is there some way to solve this?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

I've been doing some problems lately and this particular equality came around:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2n}{\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\theta-x_i}
\end{equation}
Is there some way to solve for $\theta$? I've tried a lot of things but it seems that only numerical methods would suffice, and I'm not quite involved with them.

Comment: If you multiply with all denominators, you obtain a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $\theta$. Even for these, solving numerically is the best or in fact „only“ method except for small $n$

Comment: What was the origin problem?

Comment: Are looking for all roots or just a particular one ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I'm looking for possibly all the roots.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the eaquation
$$\frac{2n}{\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\theta-x_i}\qquad \implies \qquad \color{red}{n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{\theta-x_i}}$$ In this form, it is exactly the same as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436409/rigorous-estimates-on-roots-of-function/436479#436479) with $a_i=b_i$.

It is a particular case of the so-called Underwood equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i\, z_i}{ \theta-\alpha_i}=1-q$$ (let $z_i=1$ and $q=n-1$).

Our most recent work was published in $2014$ in [this paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436409/rigorous-estimates-on-roots-of-function/436479#436479) (you can also find it [here][2]) where we proposed rapid and robust solution methods using convex transformations.

If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact me.